# android multicast on several devices

Tags: android, multicast

I am doing multicast in my android apps and I have some troubles like most of people ;-)
I have created an android application which listens for multicast.
It works fine on 2 phones and one tablet (Samsung S2 & S3 and Motorola). The problem is with an Asus tablet. When I launch the application only on this device, I can receive data via multicast but when I launch the app on another device I cannot receive anymore  data on the Asus but it works on the other.

I read somewhere that some tablets don't support completly multicast but I don't really understand the meaning of "not completely".

Can anyone help me on this issue?
I will perform several test with another asus and an acer tablet next week to see if it works.

Thanks.

Anthony